# Validity of a modal argument?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Would you say that the following argument is valid?

And if not, why exactly?

> For all we know, A may be the state of B;
>
> What C does is determined by the state of B;
>
> Therefore, for all we know, what C does may be determined by A.

A, B and C should be understood as referring to "things".

Thanks.
EB

Comment: Could you give an example for A, B, and C to clarify?

Comment: What does it mean "to be the state of" ? What does it mean  "is determined by the state of " ? These expression are not "formalizable" with usual logical constants.

Comment: @Eliran - I would rather not. As soon as you give particular instances, people focus of whether the premises are true or not. But, you can pick up any set of three things, as long as it says something meaningful, for example, A = Water, B = H2O molcules; C = Sea. But this shouldn't be necessary. The argument is valid or it isn't, irrespective of what A, B and C are taken to mean, as long as it makes sense. EB

Comment: @Mauro - We could perhaps reduce it to that: For all we know, A may be S;
What C does is F(S);
Therefore, for all we know, what C does may be F(A).

Comment: Isn't the argument valid on the face of it as interpreted in everyday language?

Comment: Or even more simple, like that: A may be B;
F(C) is F(B);
Therefore, F(C) may be F(A).

Comment: The argument is valid.  It involves two premises and one combination of them. 
 Where could it really go wrong?  Both premises are unlikely.  Outside mathematics, nothing is truly determined by another single thing.  Whether something will boil depends on temperature and pressure... And the state of something is generally its state, and not another, separate thing.  The state of the molecular motion in a beaker is both more and less than its temperature -- they are different types of thing.  So the odds are incredibly high one of the two premises is wrong.

Comment: I understand your point. It would be accepted I think by most people with a metaphysical bent. Still, your point only applies to the truth of the premises, not to the validity of the argument. I also see the word "determine" as implying the notion in science of "all things being equal". The premises will be true for science and our ordinary, macroscopic view of the situation, if not in the eyes of God, so to speak. Your point, I think, would dismiss all exact sciences as unlikely true of most real-life situations. We in fact only need one instance of the situation that makes the premises true.

Comment: Would the following rewording also work?  
Premise 1 - ◊A = State(B); 
Premise 2 - □Does(C)=Determined-by(State(B)); 
Conclusion - ◊Does(C)=Determined-by(A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have chosen to present the problem in abstracto, I am assuming that you are not so much worried about the exact nature of *determining*.

The first, most simple formalisation that comes to mind is:

```
s(x) ... the state of x.
D(x) ... x determines what c does.
```

Then we would write

```
◊a = s(b) ... possibly a is the state of b
D(s(b))   ... the state of b determines what c does.
◊D(a)     ... possibly a determines what c does.
```

So does the last sentence follow from the first two? No it does not, one has to replace the second sentence by

```
□D(s(b))     ... it is known that the state of b determines what c does.
```

Now the third one will follow, at least in, say, S4 which was the epistemic system that Hintikka settled for. If am not mistaken, the reasoning should go through in K already.

Comment: OK, that's very helpful, thanks. I have to correct one bit: It's not "the state of a and b are the same", it's "a is the same as the state of b". I'm not sure this affects the meaning or validity, but it's the original idea. As to the necessity of premise 2, the absence of the "as far as we know" phrase was meant to convey that premise 2 is accepted as "known to be true", and perhaps therefore as necessarily true? "Necessarily true" I think is less easily understood as "known to be true", so if known implies necessarily true, we could have it both ways, logic and understandability.

Comment: And knowledge is the only certainty of truth we... know, so it would be hard to do without it. Is there a way to try and keep it?

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the part about the states. Regarding the other issue: since the modality in question is knowledge, I have corrected that as well. The second translation seems to be perfectly reasonable to me, in natural language "we know that..." is mainly used for emphasis, so often dropped, even if a sentence is claimed to be known.

Comment: That's just perfect! I was rather convinced the thing was valid but I still don't understand how it could possibly be formally proven that it is valid, even once it is properly formalised as you did. Any advice on this?

Comment: Are you looking for a proof in an axiomatic system, or a formal proof?

Comment: What's the difference? I would certainly like to have a formal proof. Can I have both?

Comment: You might be interested to look at a second question No. 59598 that I posted on a somewhat more complex argument. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/59598/semantic-expressiveness-of-modal-logic

Answer (score 0):

> Would you say that the following argument is valid?
>
> And if not, why exactly?

It is not. The connection between A and *what C does* is too accidental to allow an inference of A's [possible] determination of the latter. Thus, one can speak in terms of *coincidence*, not *causation*.

The non-conclusive premise *A may be the state of B* gives a connotation of possibility of alternatives. To the extent that the state of B could be something else, A's capacity to "influence what C does" is weakened. This applies regardless of whether A is just a *value/constant* or a *variable* on its own (apropos of [your clarification](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/59494/validity-of-a-modal-argument#comment161504_59502)).

Consider C(B)=B^2, whence B determines *what C does*. The state of B may be A=3, but the value 3 itself is not what controls C. The rule of correspondence is between C and B, not between C and one of the possible values of B.

Comment: If C(B)=B^2 then B does not determine what C does. What C does is squaring, and what B determines is what square you get. That is a category mistake.

Comment: @JishinNoben "*That is a category mistake*" ... only if one takes the position that the premise "*What C does is determined by the state of B*" means that each different input *x* (or sets thereof) ought to override/replace/redefine *f(x)*. Also a piecewise function would overcome your remark, but it would still miss the point I am making. Given the context of my answer, I think it is clear that by the language "*what C does*" I mean "*what number C produces*" in response to the input.

Comment: @Jishin - Thanks, but I don't actually understand your point! If C(B)=B^2 and B determines what C does but the state of B does not determine what C does then premise 2 is just false. You would need to find another example where the state of B does determine what C does. Also, as implied semantically by premise 1, A may well not be the same thing as the state of B, so A indeed may not determine what C does, but this is implied by the "may" of the conclusion. And if, however, A is indeed the state of B, then, obviously, A determines what C does, granted premise 2. So, I disagree with your point.

Comment: @Speakpigeon *A* is not what determines "what C does". The determination or dependence relation lies in *B* only (see your premise #2). The possible instance where the state (or value) of *B* is *A* does not imply that *A* itself causes *C*'s specific response in that scenario.

Comment: I disagree. Premise 1 semantically implies that if (not "when") A is indeed the state of B, as it may well be, it is always the state of B. There is in this case no temporal restriction, and no notion of any "instance" applicable. A is just the state of B. The two are the same thing under a different label. So, granted premise 2, I don't see how the conclusion could be false, and in fact could possibly be necessarily false.

Comment: @Speakpigeon "*semantically implies that if (not "when") A is indeed the state of B, as it may well be, it is **always** the state of B*" That is not palpable in your formulation of premise 1. You should have formulated premise 1 with enough specificity so as to make it clear that the [uncertain] state of *B* would **always** be *A*. But that in turn would weaken the notion that something else (such as "*what C does*") is determined by an *unchanging* characteristic (the state of B). The *state of* something is generally understood as a non-constant feature, that is, subject to variation.

Comment: OK, I take your point to some extent... The copula verb "be" as used in the informal argument unambiguously means identity. A is B means A is the same thing as B. Identity in this sense is not time-dependent, so there's no reason to add a specification that it is not. This, however, would be I think
more properly expressed by the sign "≡" than by the sign "=", which may refer to a time-dependent relation. Is that enough, do you think?