# Semantic expressiveness of modal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic, philosophy-of-logic, symbolic-logic

I am wondering how much of the semantic of basic philosophical questions can be expressed by formal arguments in modal logic. Here is one argument I formalised myself:

> P1  ◇ ∀a, ∃x // GNB(x, a) ∧ C(a) ≡ S(x)
>
> P2 ◻ ∀b, ∃y // GNB(y, b) ∧ A(b) ≡ F(S(y))
>
> C  ◇ ∀c // A(c) ≡ F(C(c))

The original argument, in ordinary language, proved very difficult to understand for most people I have tested with it.

Is it possible to prove the validity of such an argument in a formal way, given its apparent complexity for most people? How complex proven arguments can be? Could you give a representative example of a complex argument?

Comment: Is `GNB` a single predicate symbol?

Comment: I am unsure of the symbolism; it would be a great help if you explain them.

Comment: I'm not sure that the argument is formally valid; forget about GNB... we instantiate the universal quantifiers of P1 and P2 with **c**, but the **x** of P1 and the **y** of P2 can be different. Thus, we have **C(c)=S(x1)** from P1 and **A(c)=F(S(x2))** from P2 and we cannot perform the required substitution.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Yes, GNB(x, a) could be rewritten as G(x, a) for example.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost ◇ ∀a, ∃x // GNB(x, a) ∧ C(a) ≡ S(x) just mean: For all we know, it is possible that whatever a, there is at least one x such that the predicate GNB is true of the ordered pair (x, a) and that the predicate C being true of a is identical to the predicate S being true of x. Is that  enough?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  OK, that's for you to tell me. I think the argument is valid on the face of it, intuitively, so I would myself interpret the fact that it is not formally valid as an indication that something is missing in the formal method you use.

Comment: "I think the argument is valid on the face of it, intuitively, so I would myself interpret the fact that it is not formally valid as an indication that something is missing in the formal method you use" The role of formal methods is precisely to *counter* naive claims about intuition, or at least clarify the formal assumptions they assume implicitly, so that response seems ill-advised. You need to at the very least pin down what formal principles you need, which aren't present in the given formal system, to justify your argument.